# Getting live output from running unix command in python

Tags: python, shell

I am using below code for running unix commands:

```
cmd = 'ls -l'
(status,output) = commands.getstatusoutput(cmd)
print output
```

But the problem is that it shows output only after the command completed, but i want to see the output printed as the execution progresses.
`ls -l` is just dummy command, i am using some complex command in actual program.

Thanks!!

Answer (score 0):

Since this is homework, here's what to do instead of the full solution:

1. Use the `subprocess.Popen` class to call the executable. Note that the constructor takes a named `stdout` argument, and take a look at `subprocess.PIPE`.
2. Read from the `Popen` object's STDOUT pipe in a separate thread to avoid dead locks. See the `threading` module.
3. Wait until the subprocess has finished (see `Popen.wait`).
4. Wait until the thread has finished processing the output (see `Thread.join`). Note that this may very well happen *after* the subprocess has finished.

If you need more help please describe your precise problem.

Answer (score 0):

Unless there are simpler ways in Python which I'm not aware of, I believe you'll have to dig into the slightly more complex [`os.fork`](http://docs.python.org/library/os.html#os.fork) and [`os.pipe`](http://docs.python.org/library/os.html#os.pipe) functions.

Basically, the idea is to fork your process, have the child execute your command, while having its standard output redirected to a pipe which will be read by the parent. You'll easily find [examples](https://stackoverflow.com/a/872637/451980) of this kind of pattern.

Answer (score 0):

Most programs will use block buffered output if they are not connected to a tty, so you need to run the program connected to a pty; the easiest way is to use [pexpect:](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/pexpect/)

```
for line in pexpect.spawn('command arg1 arg2'):
    print line
```